# ParametricPlot inside of ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, parametric-functions, boundary-conditions, inverse

I don't know why the following is not working!
The code has a function `y[x]` then I have `g[t]` then I want to plot `y` vs inverse of `g`:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Clear[y, g, x, t, d, b, f, m]

a = 0.7; b = 0.001; d = 0.1; f = 1.3; m = 0.7; x0 = 60;

y[x_] := x0*Sqrt[Sqrt[a - b/x^2] + d];

Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 10}]

g[t_, d_, b_, f_, m_]:=(Sqrt[a]*Log[12*Sqrt[a]*f^2*(t*Sqrt[a]+Sqrt[t^2*a-b])])/m-(ArcTanh[(t*d)/Sqrt[a*t^2-b]]*d)/m-(Log[3*f*(-b+t^2*m)]*d)/(2*m)

ParametricPlot[{{g[x, 0.1, -0.001, 1.3, 0.7], x}}, {x, 0.1, 10}]

ParametricPlot[{y[x],ParametricPlot[{g[x, 0.1, -0.001, 1.3, 0.7], x}]}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: e.g., If `p1 = ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]` then `Head[p1]` is `Graphics` and you are trying to include this inside your plot.

Comment: Try something like `ParametricPlot[{y[x], g[x, 0.1, -0.001, 1.3, 0.7]}, {x, 1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]` for your final line of code.

Comment: I would like to see y[g^-1[t]]

Comment: Please, have a look at the comment of @bbgodfrey, it is a good solution. Moreover, it does not require any inverse functions.

Comment: We should plot `ParametricPlot[{ g[x, 0.1, -0.001, 1.3, 0.7],y[x]}, {x, 1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]` instead of `{y[x], g[x, 0.1, -0.001, 1.3, 0.7]}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but here is a guess:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Clear[y, g, x, t, d, b, f, m]

a = 0.7; b = 0.001; d = 0.1; f = 1.3; m = 0.7; x0 = 60;

y[x_] := x0*Sqrt[Sqrt[a - b/x^2] + d];

LogLinearPlot[y[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
 g[t_, d_, b_, f_, 
      m_] := (Sqrt[a]*Log[12*Sqrt[a]*f^2*(t*Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[t^2*a - b])])/
       m - (ArcTanh[(t*d)/Sqrt[a*t^2 - b]]*d)/
       m - (Log[3*f*(-b + t^2*m)]*d)/(2*m)
```

Calculate some values for the inverse function and then interpolate

```
  vals = Table[{g[x, d, b, f, m], x}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}];
h = Interpolation[vals];
{g1, g2} = h[[1, 1]];
ParametricPlot[{h[t], y[t]}, {t, g1, g2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> {"y", "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), \(-1\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

Is this now what you need?

Comment: I want to plot y[x] vs InverseFunction [g][x]

Comment: I guess it is better I say like this g[x]=t then x=g^-1[t] so now y[g^-1[t]]

Comment: h[x]=InverseFunction[g][x] so how to plot parametric y vs h ?!

Comment: I'm checking it. I will let you know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. Since we plot
$$y=y(g^{-1}(x))$$
so we can use `InverseFunction`.

```
gg[x_] = g[x, 0.1, -0.001, 1.3, 0.7];
fig1=Plot[y@InverseFunction[gg][x], {x, -5, 5},AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

The other way is $x=g(t)$,then $t=g^{-1}(x)$,$y(t)=y(g^{-1}(x))$,so we plot `ParametricPlot`  $(g(t),y(t))$

```
gg[x_] = g[x, 0.1, -0.001, 1.3, 0.7];
fig2=ParametricPlot[{gg[t], y[t]}, {t, -20, 20}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1,PlotStyle->Red]
```

We can compare the two way.

```
Show[fig1, fig2]
```

[image]